# Android NDK Output section Missing under Paths and Symbols

Tags: android, android-ndk

In my Android NDK project, I right clicked the project and under C/C++ General-->Paths and Symbols  there are sections for

```
includes, symbols, libraries, library paths, source location, reference
```

but its missing Output section. In other word, when I did NDK-build my C++ files along with Adnroid,mk  the its corresponding yyyy.so are not inside my libs folder of the project.

I think there should be a output section under the Paths and Symbols where the generated or ndk built yyyy.so should be placed.

jni folder contains all the C++ files and Android.mk and the yyyy.so the result of the built.

Comment: have you tried to manually type in command "ndk-build" on terminal?

Comment: yes, I manually did ndk-build at terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Might not solve the problem of Eclipse, but you can try adding NDK_APP_OUT := path/to/your/lib/dir to Application.mk and your libraries will be created at that location.